# Custom Style to a form created using react-json schema form

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

I am trying to create a form using react-json schema-form. I am new to the custom templates for the same. I would like to have all the widgets in the form in  a single row. How to do that ?

i have tried the following (component) , which was from the custom Object from their website, but couldn't get the desired result.

```
import React from 'react';

import Form from 'react-jsonschema-form';

/* this is my schma*/
const AdHocCheckSchema = {
    title: "search",

    type: "object",

    required: ["searchKeyword", "country"],

    properties: {

        searchKeyWord: {

            type: "string",

            title: "Search Keyword"

        },
        country: {
            type: "string",

            title: "country",

            enum: [
                "a",
                "b"
            ],
            enumNames: [
                "a",
                "b"
            ]
        }
    }
};

/*this is the ui schema*/

const adHocCheckUiSchema = {

    "ui:order": [
        "searchKeyWord",
        "country"
    ],
    "country": {
        "ui:widget": "select"
    }

};

function CustomTemplate(props) 
{    
   return (
        <div>
            {props.title} 

            {props.description}

            {props.properties.map(
             element => 
             <div className="property-wrapper">{element.content}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
}

const AdHocCheckComponent = () => {
    return (

            <Form
                className="tp-adhoccheck__horizontal"
                schema={AdHocCheckSchema}
                uiSchema={adHocCheckUiSchema}
                CustomTemplate={CustomTemplate}
            />


    );
};

export default AdHocCheckComponent;
```

i have no idea how to make the input field , select widget and also the button in same line. As of now its looking as in a default form one line after another.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the look and feel of each field via their templates. Given that the form submits as an object, you'd want to tweak the ObjectFieldTemplate:
https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-customization/#object-field-template

In fact, if you go to their playground (https://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/, "Custom Object" tab link on top), you'll see all the fields in a single row (if your screen resolution is high enough, otherwise they will wrap over into subsequent rows). Their source code for that effect (via a custom ObjectFieldTemplate component( is located here: https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/blob/master/playground/samples/customObject.js

```
function ObjectFieldTemplate({ TitleField, properties, title, description }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <TitleField title={title} />
      <div className="row">
        {properties.map(prop => (
          <div
            className="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"
            key={prop.content.key}>
            {prop.content}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      {description}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i used customFieldTemplate and flex-box and could make it in  a row

```js
export const customFieldTemplate = (props) => {
    const {id, label, classNames, required, errors, children} = props;
    return (
        <div className={classNames}>
            <label className="field_label" htmlFor={id}>
                <span className="required-field">
                    {required ? '*' : null}
                </span>
                {label}
            </label>
            {children}
            {errors}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using typescript and in my case here is the answer

```
function ObjectFieldTemplate(props: ObjectFieldTemplateProps) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>
        <p>{props.description}</p>
        {props.properties.map((element) => (
          <div className='property-wrapper'>{element.content}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

<Form
      formData={formState}
      schema={schema as JSONSchema7}
      transformErrors={transformErrors}
      onChange={(e) => setFormState(e.formData)}
      validator={validator}
      onSubmit={() => onSubmit}
      templates={{ ObjectFieldTemplate }}
    >
```

Ref:
https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-customization/custom-templates/