# How to prevent fields in react-json-schema-form from appearing row by row

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-jsonschema-forms

I am creating forms using React-json-schema-form. I don't understand how am I suppose to change the layout of the forms I create. They appear in rows by default and adding classes to each field in the uiSchema does not reflect the desired change. I tried adding col-3 etc and they neither change size nor stop appearing in rows.

Its so complex to figure out. My understand would be to change the default behaviour of the fields. But, I'm sure it should be able to be designed out of the box right?

[image]

This is what I want to do but its outdated and I still don't know how to use it. https://github.com/audibene-labs/react-jsonschema-form-layout.

How do I change the layout?

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import axios, { existing_api, new_api, public_path } from "../../../Api/api";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
//import Form from "@rjsf/core"; 
import Form from "@rjsf/bootstrap-4";



class POSView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hotelId: 1,
            isActive: 1,
            formData: { 'recordIn': 10096 },
            schema: props.schema || {
                "title": "POS",
                "description": "Add POS Invoice - Rooms",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "customer": { "title": "Customer", "type": 'string', "default": '' },
                    "room": { "title": "Room", "type": 'integer', "default": '' },
                    "address": { "title": "Address", "type": 'string' },
                    "company": { "title": "Company", "type": 'string' },
                    "dueAmount": { "title": "Due Amount", "type": 'string' },
                    "roomRate": { "title": "Room Rate", "type": 'string' },
                    "recordIn": { "title": "Record In", "type": 'number', enum: [10096, 10097], enumNames: ["Guest Ledger Control A/c", "Accounts Receivable"] },
                    "department": { "title": "Department", "type": 'number', enum: [1, 2], enumNames: ["Head Office", "Accounts"] },
                    "id": { "title": "ID", "type": 'string' },
                    "invoiceNumber": { "title": "Invoice Number", "type": 'string' },
                    "invoiceDate": { "title": "Invoice Date", "type": 'string', "format": "date-time" },
                    "btcCompany": { "title": "BTC Company", "type": 'number', enum: [1, 2], enumNames: ["Limited Standard", "Standard Limited"] },


                    "itemsAndServices":
                    {
                        "title": "Item And Service",
                        "description": "Add items and Services",
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            //"required": [''],
                            "properties":
                            {
                                "Number": { "type": "number" },
                                "Item Name": {
                                    "title": "Item Name",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Item Notes": {
                                    "title": "Item Notes",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Qty": {
                                    "title": "Qty",
                                    "type": "number"
                                },
                                "Unit": {
                                    "title": "Unit",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Price": {
                                    "title": "Price",
                                    "type": "number"
                                },
                                "%": {
                                    "title": "%",
                                    "type": "number"
                                },
                                "Extended": {
                                    "title": "Extended",
                                    "type": "number"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    "payment":
                    {
                        "title": "Payment",
                        "description": "",
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            //"required": [''],
                            "properties":
                            {
                                "date": { "title": "Date", "type": "string", format: "date-time" },
                                "amount": { "title": "Amount", "type": "number" },
                                "cheque": { "title": "Cheque #", "type": "integer" },
                                "memo": { "title": "Memo", "type": "string" },
                                "recordIn": { "title": "Record In", "type": 'number', enum: [10096, 10097], enumNames: ["Guest Ledger Control A/c", "Accounts Receivable"] },
                                // dynamically populate


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            uiSchema: props.uiSchema || {
                // customer:{'className':""},
                // room:{'className':"", },
                // address: {'className':"",  "ui:disabled": true, },
                // company: {'className':"",  "ui:disabled": true, },
                // dueAmount: {'className':"",  "ui:disabled": true, },
                // roomRate: {'className':"",  "ui:disabled": true, },
                // recordIn:{'className':"", },
                // department:{'className':"", },
                // id:{'className':"", },
                // invoiceNumber: {'className':"",  "ui:disabled": true, },
                // invoiceDate:{'className':"", },
                // btcCompany:{'className':"", },
                // itemsAndServices:{'className':""},
                //items: { className: "container col-offset-6 col-md-3" }

            //     'ui:field': 'layout', HOW I expected the default library to work
            //     'ui:layout': [
            //         {
            //             customer: { md: 6 },
            //             room: { md: 6 }
            //         }, {
            //             address: { md: 12 }
            //         }, {
            //             company: { md: 6 },
            //             dueAmount: { md: 6 }
            //         }
            //       ]
            // },
            // fields: 
            // {
            //     layout: LayoutField
            }
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    };

   

    onChange({ formData }) {
        formData.address = "";
        console.log(formData);
        this.state.schema.description = "this is beta plus plus";

        this.setState({
            formData: formData,

        });
    }

    handleSubmit({ formData }) {
        // Submit to an api
        console.log(formData);
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="col-4"> 
                    {/* <div class="row">
                        <h1 class="col">First Form</h1>
                    </div><br /> */}

                    <div>
                        <Form
                            schema={this.state.schema}
                            formData={this.state.formData}
                            uiSchema={this.state.uiSchema}
                            //fields={this.state.fields}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
                    </div>
                 
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }


}
export default POSView;
```

Comment: Checking this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571931/custom-style-to-a-form-created-using-react-json-schema-form
If it works, this might be a duplicate. But more information is welcome